# How to connect mobile app (Ionic 2) to IBM IoT using IBM IoTF nodeJS library

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ionic2, watson-iot

I am on a Cordova based IoT project. I'm using Ionic 2 framework (Typescript).

And precisely the problem is : I'm having problem connecting the mobile app to the IBM IoT platform.

:: On the front-end ::

I have the Browserified version of the mobile app code (`app.bundle.js`).

:: On the back end ::

I have the `server.js` file according to the generic structure of a Loopback application.

Here's the problem I'm currently having :

1. IBM IoTf is a nodeJS library. But it has a Browserified bundled version (`iotf-client.bundle.js`). And the app has also a Browserified bundled version (`app.bundle.js`).
   If I use both the bundled version in my app build process, only one of the functionalities - either app or IBM IoT works; but not the both. Because IBMIoTF is not getting available to window global object.
2. The app backend (`server.js`) is not connected to the Bluemix. If I try to connect & initialize it to the Bluemix platform by using ibmbluemix nodeJS package (which is deprecated as of now), then the mobile front-end is getting not connected to the Bluemix platform. So, I can deduce that I cannot connect & initialize the Bluemix SDK from both mobile front-end & back-end.

   In this situation, how I'm supposed to communicate from mobile app to mobile back-end to connect to IBM IoT platform? Is it using simple GET / POST HTTP request?
   If yes, then I have also tried to send a HTTP POST request from Ionic (which is bundled in app.bundled.js) to mobile backend (server.js). But nothing is happening.

PS : I already have installed `cordova-whitelist` plugin

Here's the project URL :

https://github.com/somnathbm/pearl